# jQuery's slideToggle does both slideDown and slideUp in IE8 simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

I've uploaded my problem here : http://gotchance.com/k2/

Try clicking on the "Login" link. It works fine in FF and Safari. However in IE8, the form slides down and then slides up again automatically.

For testing purpose, i added 4 more "test" links and found that only the links inside #navigation div cause this problem.

Also, if i toggle using any other element like "button" "input", it works fine. Only the "a" tags inside the "#navigation" cause the problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the login button more specific to the jQuery selector **$("a#loginLink")** instead of **$("a")**?

Comment: yeah, i even tried this $('#wrap #header #navigation ul li a#loginLink') and everything in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html does not validate. Always make sure you run it through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org) first. An invalid dom can play hell with jquery selectors (especially in ie).

Also I have noticed that the rounded and font plugins produce some odd markup which may also cause issues.

Have you tried stripping the page down to its bare bones then adding the functionality a piece at a time ensuring after every step your toggle is working.

Comment: Thanks :) that helped. The problem was due to the the corners plugin.

Now,
1) Can you suggest some other rounded corners plugin ?
2) And, when the login form slides back up, the heading "Welcome to Kontactr" moves few pixels up and touches the green-line. Then it comes down automatically. Any idea what is causing that ?

Comment: In my opinion all the rounded corner plugins have issues and use far too much extra markup. I use images or just use the css and moz-border-radius, of course ie users will have to suffer without!!

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you have an extra comma in your custom.js file.  The extra comma is on line 25.

Before:

```
   confirm: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#rpassword"
        },
    },
```

After:

```
confirm: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#rpassword"
        }
    },
```

I don't know if that will solve your problem though.